# Arithmetic with congruence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to compute the following expression in $\mathbb{Z}_{5, +, \cdot}$ : $$ [2]_5^4 - [4]_5^4 \cdot [3]_5^4 \cdot [2]_5^4 $$  I'm not sure what is the best way to do this. Should I determine all the terms separately first? For example, for the second term $$ 4^1 = 4 \\ 4^2 = 16 = 1 \\ 4^3 = 4 \cdot 1 = 4 \\ 4^4 = 4 \cdot 4 = 1 $$ etc. So this means $[4]_5^4 = [1]_5$ ? Also, I'm not sure if I can use Fermat little theorem here, which says that if $p$ is prime and doesn't divide $a$, then $[1]_p = [a^{p-1}]_p$. But can I say that $[a^{p-1}]_p = [a]_p^{p-1} $ or is this false?

Comment: I deleted my answer, possibly temporarily, because I think I may be misunderstanding this.  Why is $4^1 = 1$?

Comment: Ah sorry, I made a mistake. Let me correct it!

Comment: Yes you can say: the map $\mathbf Z \to \mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, $a\mapsto a\bmod 5$  is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $[a^{p-1}]_p = [a]_p^{p-1}$ because $[xy]_p = [x]_p[y]_p$ for all $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}_5$.

You're on the right track but I wouldn't say it like "$4^2 = 1$" because that's technically incorrect.  It's better to use modular equivalences, as in "$4^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$."

Let me know if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use *Lil' Fermat*: for any $a\not\equiv0\mod 5$, one has $\;a^4\equiv 1\mod 5$.

Comment: Ok. If I apply this here, does it mean that $[3]_5^4 = [3^4]_5 = [1]_5$ and also $[2]_5^4 = [1]_5$?

Comment: It's exactly so.

Comment: @Wythagoras: You don't like the affectionate name I use for Little Fermat's theorem?